# Modal shows up after second button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue. After clicking on button with content "CHECK TASKS" nothing happens. But when I click second time the button, the modal shows up. I want to make it showed up after first click.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container__panels">
            <div class="tasks panel">
                <h1 class="panel__headline">TASKS</h1>
                <button class="panel__button">CHECK TASKS</button>
            </div>
            <div class="events panel">
                <h1 class="panel__headline">EVENTS</h1>
                <button class=" panel__button">CHECK EVENTS</button>
            </div>
            <div class="reminder panel">
                <h1 class="panel__headline">REMINDERS</h1>
                <button class="panel__button" >CHECK REMINDERS</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
        <button class="modal__exit">X</button>
    </div>
    <script src="classes.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
}

.container__panels{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
   
}

.panel{
    text-align: center;
    flex: 0 1 300px;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(5, 1fr) / 1fr;
}

.panel__headline{
    margin: 1em 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.panel__button{
    cursor: pointer;
    grid-row-start: 5;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #474554;
    color: #F1F1F1;
}

.panel__button:hover{
    color: #929297;
}

/* MODAL */

.modal{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.modal__exit{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 1em 2em;
}
```

classes.js CODE:

```
"use strict"

class Modal {
    constructor(buttons, modal, closeBtn) {
        this.buttons = buttons;
        this.modal = modal;
        this.closeBtn = closeBtn;
    }

    showModal() {
        this.buttons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if (button.textContent === "CHECK TASKS") {
                    this.modal.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            });
        });
    }

    closeModal() {
        if (this.closeBtn) {
            this.closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
                this.modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
            });
        }
    }
}
```

script.js CODE:

```
"use strict";

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".panel__button");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".modal__exit");

const modalInstance = new Modal(buttons, modal, closeBtn);

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modalInstance.showModal();
    });
});

if (closeBtn) {
    closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modalInstance.closeModal();
    });
}
```

What should I do? I have no idea what to do, I am a begginer.

Comment: Because you add the listener after clicking the button. Why the modal has a list of buttons in the first place? Shouldn't each modal have one button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are duplicating the `addEventListener` method during click event for `showModal()`:

- First you are invoking addEventListener on every button in `script.js`
- Then again on `classes.js` during calling `showModal()`

This skips showModal on first click since it is not setting modal visibility to `visible`. Only during the second click the `visible` property is set to modal.

You can actually simplify the code and get rid of a lot of code duplicity.

I have refactored your code as follows:

- Removed duplicity of addEventListener during call of showModal() function
- showModal() and closeModal() functions now does one thing only, following Single Responsibily Principle (SRP)
- Added showModal() and closeModal() on modals of all 3 buttons (Which makes sense, right?)

#### Check the following refactored code:

```js
"use strict";

class Modal {
  constructor(buttons, modal, closeBtn) {
    this.buttons = buttons;
    this.modal = modal;
    this.closeBtn = closeBtn;
  }

  showModal() {
    this.modal.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".panel__button");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".modal__exit");

const modalInstance = new Modal(buttons, modal, closeBtn);

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modalInstance.showModal();
  });
});

if (closeBtn) {
  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modalInstance.closeModal();
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
}

.container__panels {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 1 300px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(5, 1fr) / 1fr;
}

.panel__headline {
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.panel__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  grid-row-start: 5;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #474554;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.panel__button:hover {
  color: #929297;
}


/* MODAL */

.modal {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.modal__exit {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  /* Modified */
  top: 6em;
  /* Modified */
  padding: 1em 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container__panels">
      <div class="tasks panel">
        <h1 class="panel__headline">TASKS</h1>
        <button class="panel__button">CHECK TASKS</button>
      </div>
      <div class="events panel">
        <h1 class="panel__headline">EVENTS</h1>
        <button class="panel__button">CHECK EVENTS</button>
      </div>
      <div class="reminder panel">
        <h1 class="panel__headline">REMINDERS</h1>
        <button class="panel__button">CHECK REMINDERS</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal">
    <button class="modal__exit">X</button>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** View in full page mode, otherwise due to css issue closeBtn gets hidden